# Convert string into array using regular expression in jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
<script>
    var str='strat with any string[A][/A][X][/X]test string[C][/C]End with any string[C][/C]';
</script>
```

how can i convert above string into array, so that it can be shown as below array using jquery , regular expression

converted array should display like

```
<script>
var arr= new Array();
arr[]='strat with any string';
arr[]='[A][/A]';
arr[]='[X][/X]';
arr[]='test string';
arr[]='[C][/C]';
arr[]='End with any string';
arr[]='[C][/C]';
</script>
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on? What has your research lead you to? More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `arr[]=…` is a SyntaxError in JavaScript.

Comment: I would like to split string into array as bellow
 <script>
     var str='strat with any string[A][/A][X][/X]test string[C][/C]End with any string[C][/C]';
  var arr== ["strat with any string", "[A][/A]", "[X][/X]", "test string", "[C][/C]", "End with any string", "[C][/C]"];
    </script>

Comment: I want each sub string into separate element element like  arr== ["strat with any string", "[A][/A]", "[X][/X]", "test string", "[C][/C]", "End with any string", "[C][/C]"];

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
str.split(/(\[[A-Z]\]\[\/[A-Z]\])/g)
```

Maybe you will get empty string (because of `[A][/A][X][/X]` but you can easily remove them.

Comment: I would like each substring